# LINQ C# FirstOrDefault() query return null for the existing element

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I want to perform some simple queries for these below models using EF Core code first.

`Post` model

```
public class Post
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Title { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public int FirstTagId { get; set; }
    public FirstTag FirstTag { get; set; }
    public int SecondTagId { get; set; }
    public SecondTag SecondTag { get; set; }
}
```

`FirstTag` model

```
public class FirstTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string tagName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Post { get; set; }
}
```

`SecondTag` model

```
public class SecondTag
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string tagName { get; set; }
    public ICollection<Post> Post { get; set; }
}
```

My intention is that when I create a new post. I want to check that does the tag will be inserted into the new post exists or not using the below check operation

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Post>> CreatePost([FromBody] NewPostParam postParam)
{
    // to prevent inserting duplicate first tag
    var tag1 = _context.FirstTags.Where(x =>
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postParam.Post.FirstTag.tagName) || x.tagName == postParam.Post.FirstTag.tagName))
        .FirstOrDefault();
    // to prevent inserting duplicate second tag 
    var tag2 = _context.SecondTags.Where(x =>
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postParam.Post.SecondTag.tagName) || x.tagName == postParam.Post.SecondTag.tagName))
        .FirstOrDefault();

    if (tag1 == null)
    {
        tag1 = new FirstTag
        {
            tagName = "tag1 test",
            tagDescription = "tag1 test des!!"
        };
        _context.FirstTags.Add(tag1);
    }
    if (tag2 == null)
    {
        tag2 = new SecondTag
        {
            tagName = "tag2 test",
            tagDescription = "tag2 test des!"
        };
        _context.SecondTags.Add(tag2);
    }
     var newPost = new Post
     {
        Title = postParam.Post.Title,
        Description = postParam.Post.Description,
        FirstTag = tag1 != null ? tag1 : postParam.Post.FirstTag,
        SecondTag = tag2 != null ? tag2 : postParam.Post.SecondTag,
     };

    _context.Posts.Add(newPost);
    // remain code ...
}
```

This is the currently existing tags database

`FirstTag` table

```
Id  |  tagName
1     firstTag1
2     firstTag2
```

`SecondTag` table

```
Id  |  tagName 
1      secondTag1
2      secondTag2
```

And this is my JSON data for adding new post

```
{
    "post": {
        "title": "post2 test titlte",
        "description": "post2 test description!",
         "firstTag": {
            "tagName": "firstTag1",
            "tagDescription": "firstTag des!!"
        },
        "secondTag": {
            "tagName": "secondTag2",
            "tagDescription": "secondTag des!!"
        }
    }
}
```

I've tried several times to add the same name for `FirstTag` and `SecondTag`. But the new data is just created and the check operation I performed above maybe did nothing to prevent that. What do I do to prevent duplicate data from being inserted?

Comment: Serializable transaction?

Comment: Don't forget to accept an answer if it helped you.

Answer (score 1):

Unless you did not post something from your data model, `FirstTag` and `SecondTag` should be the same Model, or at the very least inherit from the same base model.

Your class `Post` does not contain the definition for `SecondTag` but I'll assume it's the same as `FirstTag`. You're also missing `Id` in your JSON example.

Ignoring those inconsistencies, you're first defining 2 variables in your `CreatePost`: `tag1` and `tag2`. Since `postParam` will not have a filled tag, both of these variables will initialize as `null`. As such, it's logical that both if statements will validate as `true`

So, what you want to do is more along the lines of:

```
[HttpPost]
public async Task<ActionResult<Post>> CreatePost([FromBody] NewPostParam postParam)
{
    // to prevent inserting duplicate first tag
    var tag1 = _context.FirstTags.Where(x =>
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postParam.Post.FirstTag.tagName) || x.tagName == postParam.Post.FirstTag.tagName))
        .FirstOrDefault();
SecondTag tag2 = null;

if (tag1 == null)
{
    tag1 = new FirstTag
    {
        tagName = "tag1 test",
        tagDescription = "tag1 test des!!"
    };
    _context.FirstTags.Add(tag1);
}
else
{
   tag2 = _context.SecondTags.Where(x =>
        (string.IsNullOrEmpty(postParam.Post.SecondTag.tagName) || x.tagName == postParam.Post.SecondTag.tagName))
        .FirstOrDefault();

   if (tag2 == null)
   {       
       tag2 = new SecondTag
       {
           tagName = "tag2 test",
           tagDescription = "tag2 test des!"
       };
       _context.SecondTags.Add(tag2);
   }
}
 var newPost = new Post
 {
    Title = postParam.Post.Title,
    Description = postParam.Post.Description,
    FirstTag = tag1 != null ? tag1 : postParam.Post.FirstTag,
    SecondTag = tag2 != null ? tag2 : postParam.Post.SecondTag,
 };

_context.Posts.Add(newPost);
// remain code ...
}
```

Secondly, you're not checking whether `tag1` already has a value like `tag2`. If you NEVER want tag2 to be filled with a tag of tag1, do something like this:

```
tag2 = _context.SecondTags.FirstOrDefault(x =>
            string.IsNullOrEmpty(postParam.Post.SecondTag.tagName) ||  (x.tagName == postParam.Post.SecondTag.tagName && postParam.Post.FirstTag.tagName != x.tagName));
```

Answer (score 1):

Ignoring some questionable aspects of your design, try this:

```
if(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postParam.Post.FirstTag.tagName))
{
    if(!_context.FirstTags.Any(t => t.tagName.Trim().ToLower() == postParam.Post.FirstTag.tagName.Trim().ToLower()))
    {
        var tag1 = new FirstTag
        {
            tagName = "tag1 test",
            tagDescription = "tag1 test des!!"
        };
        _context.FirstTags.Add(tag1);
    }
}

if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(postParam.Post.SecondTag.tagName))
{
    if (!_context.FirstTags.Any(t => t.tagName.Trim().ToLower() == postParam.Post.SecondTag.tagName.Trim().ToLower()))
    {
        var tag2 = new FirstTag
        {
            tagName = "tag1 test",
            tagDescription = "tag1 test des!!"
        };
        _context.SecondTags.Add(tag2);
    }
}
```

As you can see, I separated validation of the model value from the query. I personally dislike convoluted one-liners that make things hard to understand.

The code checks if there is match, taking into account padding and casing (since I don't know much about your backend).

Back to the questionable design. Notice how the code is suspiciously repetitive?
(Hint: It has to do with the fact that a tag is a tag, regardless of its order or how many there are.)

Comment: Thanks for your kind comment and hints. For your question, the purpose of this design is that I want users can insert 1-or-N tags to a post. For the many-to-many between Post and Tag, I could not come up with how to enable users can insert multiple tags at a time when creating a new post.

Comment: @K_ng There are ways, but I am mostly concerned about the data store design. Two tables storing identical entities is a code smell... :-)

Comment: I see and appreciate your advice. Could you give me some hints about that design?

Comment: @K_ng Well, tags are tags, so I would have a single container for the tags and then I would associate them to the different posts with a relationship. Assuming your data store is a database, I would create a table for the tags, a table for the posts and a relationship table to connect a tag to a post.

Answer (score 1):

You can check for duplicate records as follows

```
var isDuplicate = _context.FirstTags.Any(x =>x.tagName == postParam.Post.FirstTag.tagName)
if(isDuplicate){
  //Do something
}
```